# What is this 0.35mm mezzanine/FFC (?) connector?

Tags: connector, identification

This connector is used in Retina LCD controller boards to connect the LED strings. Pin pitch measures at 0.35mm, height 0.7mm, overall dimensions (with leads) about 4x2.5mm. Couldn't find it at the usual distributors or at Hirose, I-PEX, JAE and Molex, but of course it could be something else or I could be mistaken.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a custom pin count variant of JAE WP25D. Stock parts have 10, 28 or 38 pins.

Answer (score 0):

It is an `FPC to board connector`.

This may be a match.

https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM23FR?lang=en

Comment: I looked at Hirose. BM23FR header is narrower and has a 120-degree angle and metal ground contacts on each end. This one has flat ends and ground contacts only on the long sides.